# Trying to refrence a specific part of a JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON data coming from a server and being stored in a variable as an array that I need to access a specific part of to run an if statement checking if an html form submission matches any of the , in this case 3, "pin" elements.

Here is the log of what i get when I use

```
console.log(json.details);
```

Here is what i get back:

```
0: Object
ID: "4"
cohort_name: "Bill Jones"
pin: "53870"
start_date: "2014-08-02"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
ID: "5"
cohort_name: "Tracey Smith"
pin: "19224"
start_date: "2014-08-04"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
ID: "6"
cohort_name: "Joe Bloggs"
pin: "12345"
start_date: "2014-08-04"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

How would I reference the "pin" element within this array to run a check against it?

Comment: I use Firebug, myself. Are those Elements 0, 1, and 2 of an Array of Objects? Show us the code.

Comment: yes theyre element of an object, would you like to see ajax request? Or what part do you want to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var current;
for(var i = 0; i < json.details.length; i++){
  current = json.details[i];
  if(current.pin != null){
    console.log("pin is non-null and defined");
  }
}
```

Comment: with a little bit of tweaking to the if statement, changing the "!= null" to "== input", which is my variable holding the form data it now logs when a correct pin is correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would loop and check:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.details.length; i++) {
    var pin = json.details[i].pin; //pin for the object being iterated over
    //check logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would reference the array the usual way in javascript and the the object name:

```
if(Array[index].pin == CHECK)
{ //do }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var jd = json.details, r = [];
for(var i in jd){
  var cur_pin = jd[i].pin;
  if(cur_pin === 'SOMETHING HERE'){
    r.push(jd[i].pin);
  }
}
// Array `r` now has all the pins that equal 'SOMETHING HERE'
```